# Given this outline what is wrong with the code I wrote? please be explicit in explaining why something doesn't work

Tags: java, class, methods

Write the definition of a class  Player containing: 
An instance variable  name of type  String , initialized to the empty String.
An instance variable  score of type  int , initialized to zero.
A method called  setName that has one parameter, whose value it assigns to the instance variable  name .
A method called  setScore that has one parameter, whose value it assigns to the instance variable  score .
A method called  getName that has no parameters and that returns the value of the instance variable  name . 
A method called  getScore that has no parameters and that returns the value of the instance variable  score . 
 No constructor need be defined.

```
 public class Player{
 private String name;
 private int score = 0;

 public void setName(String nm)
 {name = nm;}

 public void setScore(int sc)
 {score = sc;}

 public String getName() 
 {return name;}

 public int getScore()
  {return score;}
 }
```

thank you.

Comment: How about you describe what you *think* is wrong. In other words, provide some actual information regarding expectations vs behavior, and so on.

Comment: I'm concerned about the assignment of proper types for the methods.
As far as void and other method types go I'm pretty new to type assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm not going to be "explicit" in terms of just giving you the answer, but hopefully I can help you fix it for yourself...)

Well, here's the start of what you've said you're meant to do:

> Write the definition of a class Player containing: An instance variable name of type String , initialized to the empty String.

Your code:

> private String name;

In what way is that initialized to the empty string?

To think about it another way: what would you expect the result of calling `length()` on an empty string to be? What happens if you try calling it on your variable?